# Students appearing at/in/for the written examination

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

> The number of students appearing **at** the written examination increases every year.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct ? This is a error spotting question asked in my exam although **for** sounds better here but is using *at* grammatically incorrect ?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that ***appearing*** is an unlikely/non-idiomatic word in this context. Probably most native speakers would simply refer to *the number of students **taking** the written examination*. If for some reason it's important to convey the specific allusions of ***appearing***, it might be better to consider alternatives such as ***show up, turn up, attend, arrive***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  if you hadn't said it was odd, I would have assumed it was just another BrE thing I didn't know about, similar to "to **sit** an exam" (which Americans don't use).

Comment: @Andrew: I did actually consider including ***sit*** in the first comment, but I thought it might not be familiar to everyone. Having [just checked Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+the+exam%2Csat+the+exam&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20the%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20the%20exam%3B%2Cc0), I see you're absolutely right that it's virtually unknown in AmE (but it's at near-parity with ***take*** in BrE).

Comment: Why would it be "grammatically incorrect"? *At* is a preposition of place, isn't it? *The number of students appearing at the mouth of the  non-existent, imaginary monster  increases every year* is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

> The number of students appearing **for** the written examination increases every year.

I would use [*for*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for_1) to indicate that the purpose of the "students appearing" is to take the written examination.

> 9. preposition
>      You use **for** when you state or explain the purpose of an object, action, or activity.